# Yii framework : Load css & js in layout defined by controllers?

Tags: php, yii

My target is include difference css (or js )for difference page.
And the code for link css is locate at the layout file.

My first idea is pass variable to layout, like the way you pass variable to view,
but I found that it is "can not do that by design" from [Yii framework forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4473-how-to-pass-variable-to-a-layout/page__p__23770#entry23770).

So How will you to do for putting  `<link rel="stylesheet" ... >`  in the header (which inside layout file) ?

Please correct me if my concept is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to go to your actions, and register the CSS file for them. Example:

```
function actionIndex() {
    $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
    $cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl() . '/css/myStyle.css');
    $cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl() . '/js/myScript.js');

    // more stuff
}
```

You can also pass the script loader (not CSS) an extra parameter to decide where it goes, like so:

```
// load on document ready
$cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl() . '/js/myScript.js', CClient::POS_READY);
```

See the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail) for further help.

Comment: after using registerCssFile(), where will the code generated ? Can I control it place at some where in my layout ?

Comment: For script file, if you pass another parameter, you can pass CClient::POS_READY, CClient::POS_BEGIN, CClient::POST_END, CClient::POS_LOAD to determine where it goes. Ready is on document ready, load is on body load, begin is head, end is end of body.